# Post data to url using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, php, http

I am trying to take user input and send the data to a url on my site to do some checks against my database.  In my php script I cant display any of the POST variables.  it seems like the data is not being sent.  I am new to AppleScript so perhaps I am not doing this correctly?

**APPLESCRIPT:**

```
set email to the text returned of (display dialog "Enter in your Email:" default answer "")

set productKey to the text returned of (display dialog "Enter in your Product Key:" default answer "")

display dialog "Email: " & email & "
Product Key: " & productKey

set theURL to "http://mysite/testing.php?email=email&productKey=productKey"
do shell script "curl " & quoted form of theURL
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
echo "made it before post";


    if (!empty($_POST))
    {
        $email  = $_POST["email"];
        $productKey = $_POST["productKey"];
        echo "Made it here";
        echo $email;
        echo $productKey;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I cannot throughly test your issue, because I don't have access to your site, nonetheless, the following line of code is malformed:

```
set theURL to "http://mysite/testing.php?email=email&productKey=productKey"
```

It should be in the form of:

```
set theURL to "http://mysite/testing.php?email=" & email & "&productKey=" & productKey
```